Debug SQL query in Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to debug Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure from Visual Studio 2022. When I step into the code, I see what is shown in the screenshot. The actual stored procedure is not getting opened.
Is there any solution for this? SQL Server is on the same PC as my Visual Studio.


You're in Native mode - use SQL Debugging instead.

@Dai I don't see that option in project properties. Could you please direct me ?

How did you enter Debugging mode in the first place? Do you have an SSDT project?

Your question-post didn't say if you're using the Start Debugging command from within an SSDT (.sqlproj) project - or if you used the Attach to Process command to attach-to and debug sqlservr.exe.
...but I assume the latter...
...in which case, before you attach to sqlservr.exe you need to ensure you've selected only T-SQL Debugging, like so:


When I did this, the stored procedure got executed but "Step Into" did not happen. Its always "Step Over".

@Rocky You haven't shared any other details of your project or of any other problems so I can't really help you more besides link you to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver16

Thanks for the link. scrolling through some other topics in the link, I found that first we need to import schema into the project first for debug to work.

@Rocky, can you provide more info?  Where did you read about about "need to import schema into the project first"?  Also, are you able to debug SQL now?

@bigleftie https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-ver16
